# Audio Player : How To Handle Play/Pause Button in Custom Adapter (using list to display audio files)

Tags: java, android, xml

[screehshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6rfS.jpg)

Building Audio Player

I have build a xml view for custom adapter and now I have a single button in my xml that I am accessed in custom adapter using below lines:

```
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.liststyleforadapter, null);
```

now I am accessing `liststyleforadapter.xml` files and making functions on it.
My Problem is play/pause button, 
Basically, it is a audio player to play Audio files and 
now I have been working on it , my audio files play fine but my play pause button does not work fine, if I click on first file's button to play audio file and then click next audio file play button , problem is my first play button does not reset it's background to play shape , ....

```
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() {

    mediaPlayer.pause();

    holder.playpausebtn.setBackground(Resources.getSystem().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play));

} else {

    holder.seekBar.setProgress((int) startTime);

    mediaPlayer.start();

    holder.playpausebtn.setBackground(Resources.getSystem().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause));

}
```

How can i reset previous played audio file background to play , becuase when i click on next audio file to play , my previous audio file button does not reset to it's original background.......

Please Help!!!

Comment: can you provide a screen shots of issues.

Comment: Thanks for Reply, screenshot is provided in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, holding status of audio files like playing, not playing... In adapter, `setBackground` depends on status of audio file. When you click play or pause change status and notify adapter.